# Keep Gitlab merge request asignee history

Tags: gitlab

Since the last update of our self-hosted gitlab component, the **assignee changes** are not logged anymore on any merge request.

Just like so : (taken from Gitlab documentation)
[image: example]

Not only it allows to see the exact workflow but it can also gives informations on the timeline of these changes. All these were very helpfull.

I've searched in the changelog but it dosen't seem to be listed.

Here is my question :

Is it possible go get it back and if so, how ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably hidden the activities. At the beginning of the events, where there are tabs for *Discussion*, *Pipelines*, *Commits*, and *Changes*, there is a dropdown where you can filter out some activities. You just need to select "Show all activity", or whatever fits you best

[image]